# display: flex and unresponsive photos HTML + CSS

Tags: html, css, flexbox, frontend

I have section with articles & images:

```
<div class="section">
    <div class="container" style="display: flex;">
        <% @posts.take(4).each do |post| %>
          <div class="carda" >
            <div class="card-content">
              <%= link_to image_tag post.image.url, style: 'height: 250px; width: 400px;'%>
              <p class="title" style="margin-top: 5px; color:black">
      <%= raw link_to post.title, post  %>
              </p>
            </div>
          </div>
      <% end %>
    </div>
</div>
```

I have problem with responsive:

[image: images]

I do not know if I did this section properly for articles and I do not know how to make them responsive on mobile devices

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: `'height: 250px; width: 400px;'` this is your problem. Use classes, then style the classes with CSS. Use `display: flex`, and not fixed width or height. Read up on *flexbox*, that's what you want to use.

Answer (score 0):

The images must not have a fixed width if you want a responsive behaviour. You better put width:100%; to the images and the height that you want.
Anyway, for better responses you have to put all the implicated code in this case html and css. :)